# Bigquery partition limit exceeded

Tags: google-bigquery, partition

We have a bigquery partitioned table that has exceeded more than 4000 partitions. Eventually, we have 4435 partitions in a single table. Everything continues to work fine. Is there something that I am missing from BIGQUERY documentation because they say that they are strict to 4000 partitions per table?

Comment: How did you generate this table? With a DDL (create table) or DML (insert) it is not possible to exceed the 4000 partition limit.

Comment: The table was created by incrementally inserting data. Maybe it has different limit due to streaming nature?

Answer (score 2):

There is an exception made for partition limits for data written by [Streaming API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/streaming-data-into-bigquery). Generally data streamed through the streaming API is allowed a **larger partition limit** otherwise they're stuck in the streaming buffer.